# Converting list of dictionaries to 1D numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries, all with the same 10 keywords.

Looking for a neat way to convert it to 10 1D numpy arrays. Efficiency not important.

20 lines of code at the moment.

```
names = [x['name'] for x in fields] 
names = np.asarray(names)
```

etc.

Comment: *Efficiency not important*, for any specific reason ?

Comment: So, output would be 2D array or would it be a list of 1D arrays?

Comment: If you're using Pandas, `pd.DataFrame(fields).T.values`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a nested list comprehension :

```
[np.asarray([x[attribute] for x in fields]) for attribute in ['name', 'age', 'address']]
```

or a dict comprehension:

```
{attribute:np.asarray([x[attribute] for x in fields]) for attribute in ['name', 'age', 'address']}
```

As an example :

```
>>> fields = [{'name': 'A', 'age': 25, 'address' : 'NYC'}, {'name': 'B', 'age': 32, 'address' : 'LA'}]

>>> [np.asarray([x[attribute] for x in fields]) for attribute in ['name', 'age', 'address']]
[array(['A', 'B'],
      dtype='|S1'), array([25, 32]), array(['NYC', 'LA'],
      dtype='|S3')]
>>> {attribute:np.asarray([x[attribute] for x in fields]) for attribute in ['name', 'age', 'address']}
{'age': array([25, 32]), 'name': array(['A', 'B'],
      dtype='|S1'), 'address': array(['NYC', 'LA'],
      dtype='|S3')}
```

To get the attributes in an automatic way, you could use:

```
>>> fields[0].keys()
['age', 'name', 'address']
```

Finally, a pandas [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) probably is the most suitable type for your data:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(fields)
  address  age name
0     NYC   25    A
1      LA   32    B
```

It will be plenty fast and should allow you to do any operation you'd like to do on a list of arrays.

Comment: In brackets, `np.asarray([x[attribute] for x in fields])`?

Comment: @ZEro: Indeed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let `A` be the input list of dictionaries.

For a 2D array output with each row holding data per keyword -

```
np.column_stack([i.values() for i in A])
```

Sample run -

```
In [217]: A # input list of 2 dictionaries, each with same 3 keywords
Out[217]: 
[{'a': array([6, 8, 2]), 'b': array([7, 7, 3]), 'c': array([6, 6, 4])},
 {'a': array([4, 4, 3]), 'b': array([7, 1, 6]), 'c': array([6, 1, 5])}]

In [244]: np.column_stack([i.values() for i in A])
Out[244]: 
array([[6, 8, 2, 4, 4, 3],    # key : a
       [6, 6, 4, 6, 1, 5],    # key : c
       [7, 7, 3, 7, 1, 6]])   # key : b

# Get those keywords per row with `keys()` :
In [263]: A[0].keys()
Out[263]: ['a', 'c', 'b']
```

One more sample run-

```
In [245]: fields # sample from @Eric's solution
Out[245]: 
[{'address': 'NYC', 'age': 25, 'name': 'A'},
 {'address': 'LA', 'age': 32, 'name': 'B'}]

In [246]: np.column_stack([i.values() for i in fields])
Out[246]: 
array([['25', '32'],
       ['A', 'B'],
       ['NYC', 'LA']],
      dtype='|S21')

In [267]: fields[0].keys()
Out[267]: ['age', 'name', 'address']
```

Comment: Hmm, that lead me to `map(list, zip(*[i.values() for i in fields]))` - should work for lists storage.

Comment: @Zero Awesome! That works too. But OP wanted arrays probably. So, need to do some more with it I think.

Comment: Yea, or `np.array(zip(*[i.values() for i in fields]))`

Comment: @Zero Hmm yup that's another way.

Comment: @Zero: It depends on which Python version. `dict` values could come in distinct orders, in which case `zip(*)` wouldn't work.

Comment: @Zero: I meant to say that `i.values()` could deliver values in a different order for distinct fields. In that case, a column could have values for `age` and `name`. For my solutions, it's not clear which column comes first, but each column will have a single attribute.